# Some server giving "No input file specified"

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string, friendly-url

I need help about my htaccess. I am using the following htaccess rules it is working perfectly some servers. But some servers giving `No input file specified` I have searched some solution on stack overflow.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index\.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

For example this RewriteRule will fix `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]` the `No input file specified` but some pages are not opening like `https://www[dot]webadress[dot]com/settings?tab=page`

What do I need to do to fix `No input file specified` I need QSA in my RewriteRule.

Anyone can help me please.

Comment: What is the sample url you are hitting at browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For non-existing pages uris/requests, you could try following rules. Along with rules please make sure your index.php is residing in same folder where index.php is present. Please clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php [QSA,L]
```